# RAM usage limit for .NET applications on Windows Server 2012?

Tags: c#, .net, virtual-memory, windows-server-2012

I'm currently running into an issue where a C# application using the .NET framework v4.0
begins using virtual memory once it uses 16 GBs of RAM on a 256 GB RAM server running
Windows Server 2012.

Some additional info:

Program was compiled using Visual Studio 2012 Professional Edition, on Windows 7 Professional (64-bit binary).

I don't know of any RAM limitations that should occur in this environment, but 
have I missed something?

I've also looked at any potential causes that may be in the code, but I'm not
sure what could be causing the problem. The program uses multiple Dictionary instances.
Each dictionary contains MyClass data as its values, where MyClass is defined as:

```
public MyClass
{
    string a;
    string b;
    string c;
    Dictionary<string> subDict;
}
```

Could my usage of multiple dictionaries, which each contain a Dictionary within somehow
cause a memory limitation?

Comment: a single .NET object has a limit of 2GB (with the configurable exception of certain arrays in .NET 4.5)

Comment: Would a Dictionary fit under this definition?

Comment: If you try to  create a object larger than 2GB, you get an OutOfMemoryException. .NET 4.5 supports larger objects if you enable the <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects> setting.

Comment: This is a very common myth in Windows.  A process never *begins* using virtual memory, it uses VM from the time they start running.  How much *RAM* they use entirely depends on operating system choices and how frequently they cause page faults that gets virtual memory pages mapped to RAM.  With a further distinction between soft page faults, entirely normal for a .NET program, and hard page faults, the kind you'd have to worry about.  You'll need to provide a better diagnostic about what you think is wrong with your app.  At least use a memory profiler to get insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a question of "why is the server swapping" so much as "why is my app eating so much RAM?"

STRONG SUGGESTION:

Download the Microsoft CLR profiler:

- http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16273
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx

To your original question "Why does the server use swap even if it should have plenty of free RAM?" - there are many possible reasons.  You'll need to have administrative access to the server to determine exactly what's going on.  These links might help:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/305295/why-does-windows-2008-use-swap-before-the-memory-is-full
- http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/03/25/lock-pages-in-memory-do-you-really-need-it.aspx
  <= You need to consider not just your app, but other things running on the server as well...
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx
  *

Comment: Thanks for the tool link.  After closer inspection, I figured out that there were instances were a single Dictionary was being used to store massive amounts of data. It looks like I'm going to be able to resolve the problem by dividing up the data among multiple Dictionaries.  Voting this as the answer since the tool was most helpful.